# How to launch a single process the pipes one output into another?

Tags: c#, process

As the question states, I am trying to launch two processes from a single process call using c# process library.

So for example, I'd like to run something like:

```
application1 "arg1" "arg2" | application2 "arg1".
```

At the moment, I have it setup like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.Arguments = SEEBELOW;
startInfo.FileName = FIRSTAPPLICATIONLOCATION;

startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
proc.Start();
```

Where the process filename is "application1" and the arguments of "application1" are " "arg1" "arg2" | "application2" "arg1".

Comment: The pipe `|` is interpreted by the command processor, so you need to invoke the command processor if you want to use the pipe redirection.  `cmd.exe /k app1.exe args | app2.exe args`

Comment: Thanks Dan. Can I just confirm then, that I would do something like this:

startInfo.Filename = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/k app1.exe args | app2.exe args";

Comment: Looks like a good start to me.  Give it a shot.

Comment: Ah man, Dan-o. You have no idea how you have saved me from a deadline. Thanks man, have a great day :D